# Error: parameters are of unsupported type By scrapy sql insert

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, parameters, scrapy

cmd logs show the issue. 
But every solution I tried was failed, every single data seems to work correctly

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\meow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\meow\Desktop\hello\hello\pipelines.py", line 27, in process_item
    self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), item.values())
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

> The program details:

It works fine when creating table but doesn't insert any data at all.

This is my pipeline

```
import sqlite3

class HelloPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):#
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite")
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("create table if not exists test(test1 text, test2 text, test3 text,test4 text, test5 text, test6 text, test7 text);")        
        #pass

    def close_spider(self, spider):#
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
        #pass

    def process_item(self, item, spider):#

        col = ",".join(item.keys())       
        placeholders = ",".join(len(item) * "?")
        sql = "insert into test({}) values({})"#
        self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), item.values())

        return item
```

This is items

```
import scrapy


class HelloItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    test1 = scrapy.Field()
    ...
    test7 = scrapy.Field()
```

This is the main programme

```
class crawler(scrapy.Spider):

...

    def parse (self, response):
        for data_house in jsondata["data"]["data"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(house_detail_domain.format(data_house["post_id"]), self.parse_house_detail)


    def parse_house_detail (self, response):
    ...    

    testitem = HelloItem()

    testitem["test1"] = house_detail.select(".houseInfoTitle")[0].text        
    ...
    testitem["test7"] = house_detail.select(".facility")[0].text
    return testitem
```

BTW I also tried things like

```
self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), (item.values()))   
#
self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), (item.values(),)) 
#    
val = ",".join(item.values())
self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), (val))
etc..
```

plz tell me if there is any info missing

Comment: What happens if you try `self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), tuple(item.values()))`?

Comment: Godsh thanks! but why `self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), (item.values(),))` does not makes it tuple though?

Comment: `(...,)` *does* create a tuple, but not in the way you want. Just `print` all three cases to see what you get.

Comment: I see, sorry I am new at coding  and don't even know it MUST BE TUPLE in this SQL request(like I actually tried str() b4), thank everyone

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `execute`'s second parameter expects a tuple. You've got an array, basically, from `item.values()`. To convert to a tuple, use:

```
self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), tuple(item.values()))
```

You were thinking along the right lines, but, for example, your attempt `(item.values(),)` produces a tuple containing a single value, which is the whole of the array you get back from `values()`. `tuple(item.values())` converts the array of values into a tuple containing each value as an individual element.

Say your Items are `{ 'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2'}`. Then `(item.values(),)` is the tuple `(['value1', 'value2'])`, i.e. a tuple with one value containing an array. But `tuple(item.values())` is `('value1', 'value2')`, i.e. a tuple containing a value for every item that was in the array, which is what's needed.